# CNContactViewController setEditing true before appear

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, cncontactviewcontroller

I have a task to show the contact editing screen at once during his appearance (such as WhatsApp), I show him the following way.

```
   @objc private func presentContactEditController() {
        guard var contact = contactModel.contact else { return }
        if !contact.areKeysAvailable([CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]) {
            do {
                let contactStore = CNContactStore()
                contact = try contactStore.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contact.identifier, keysToFetch: [CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
            } catch {
                debugPrint("presentContactEditController error", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        let cnContactViewController = CNContactViewController(for: contact)
        cnContactViewController.delegate = self
        cnContactViewController.setEditing(true, animated: false)

        let contactNaviController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cnContactViewController)
        present(contactNaviController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But there is a screen with information about this contact. So I tried to do it through the heir of CNContactViewController, different methods `ViewController` life cycle, but it works only in `viewDidAppear` method, but it will be visible to the user. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that that WhatsApp create a custom screen for this purpose. Just I saw the same screen in Telegram only with a modified design.

Answer (score 1):

just change let cnContactViewController = CNContactViewController(for: contact)

to

let cvc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)

it will work for you